# How to make Rollup ignore lines of code during bundling?

Tags: rollupjs

I wonder if I can get Rollup configured to ignore specific parts of my code during bundling (similar to how @formatter:off is used with IDEs to ignore code for formatting)?

In my case I have a JS file including placeholders with invalid JS like this:

```
var foo = "bar"
##PLACEHOLDER##
console.log(foo);
```

Rollup will throw an error "Unexpected character '#'"

I simply want Rollup to ignore the pattern during bundling.